# styling select element (arrow, dropdown menu, options) with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I imagine this is not a very specific programming question.

But have you tried to style select element?

I've read that it is OS specific feature and thus without jquery using simple css it is impossible to style.

- So I wonder if anyone has tried to come up with a simple (short)
  script that rewrites select into `<ul><li>` ?
- What are drawbacks? vs clean select?
- And is it possible to style also drop down part? implementations I've seen on web are mostly half styled - only the arrow portion.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, it is not advised to style form elements directly. Neither will it do you too much good except for older IEs. Form elements have traditionally been in coherent styling as the operation system to give a consisten UI experience, so they aren't designed to be styled over. If you wish though, there are alternatives:

For select elements, there is a great plugin called [chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/)

There's also various frameworks for this such as [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) from Twitter.

Answer (score 0):

The drop down box is rendered by the OS; you can't style it completely. You need to replace the `select` with a fake.

This isn't necessarily the best plugin out there, but it works:
http://filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/

Answer (score 0):

The native HTML select control offers very limited styling. You can certainly not style the arrow or provide rich content in the dropdown with native HTML control.

You can use widgets such as dojo filteringselect (that uses ul, li etc) or one of several jquery plugins out there

http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dijit/tests/form/_autoComplete.html?testWidget=dijit.form.FilteringSelect
(see the 'rich text' example in that page)

if these are too heavy for your needs, you can always write your own JS and CSS by learning the techniques used in these widgets. Note though that for ARIA accessibility, i18N and browser compatibility, it is generally a good idea to use one of the existing popular widget unless you have a stringent performance requirement